# double free or corruption when deleting reference

Tags: c++, reference, double-free

I have a class with some basic constructor. The code in main

```
 C1 g = *new C1(2);
 delete &g;
```

**leads to error:**

```
double free or corruption
```

Isn't this code equivalent to

```
C1 *g = new C1(2);
delete g;
```

What is that thing, that I don't understand.?

Comment: Add the language tag, C++?

Comment: You meant to write `C1& g = *new C1(2)`, because otherwise there is no reference. But of course it's a horrible idea to use references this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is C++, your first snippet is equivalent to

```
C1 *p = new C1(2);
C1 g = *p;
delete &g;
```

`p` is a pointer and lies on the stack.
The location `p` points to lies on the heap.
`g` is a `C1` and lies on the stack.
`&g` (the value passed to `delete`) therefore returns a memory address from somewhere in the stack segment.

Now, if I'm not mistaken:
Variables on the stack are allocated and deallocated automatically, so while your `delete &g` is not itself causing the error, it is the automatic deallocation at the end of the function that triggers it.
Also, `g` is a *copy* of the value pointed to by `p`, and not a *reference* to it or something.
Plus `p` does not get deallocated at all.

Now, in your second snippet:

```
C1 *g = new C1(2);
delete g;
```

`g` is a pointer and lies on the stack.
The location pointed to by `g` lies on the heap.
`g` (the value passed to `delete`) therefore returns a memory address from somewhere in the heap segment, and everyone is happy.